# Unable to compile C++ code on Mac OS Sonoma

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, g++, clang

I've been trying to compile my simple program

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world" ;
}
```

But I get a bunch of errors when i compile

```
clang++ -std=c++17 e.cpp -o test:

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:144:24: note: definition of 'std::exception_ptr' is not complete until the closing '}'
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS exception_ptr
                       ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:5: error: '__abi_tag__' attribute only applies to structs, variables, functions, and namespaces
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY exception_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_() {}
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:689:37: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY'
#  define _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI
                                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:673:26: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI'
          __attribute__((__abi_tag__(_LIBCPP_TOSTRING(_LIBCPP_VERSIONED_IDENTIFIER))))
                         ^
In file included from e.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:55: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY exception_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_() {}
                                                      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:544:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__promote'
    __promote<_A1, _A2, _A3>
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:548:22: error: no template named '__promote'
    typedef typename __promote<_A1, _A2, _A3>::type __result_type;
                     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:552:12: error: call to 'hypot' is ambiguous
    return hypot((__result_type)__lcpp_x, (__result_type)__lcpp_y, (__result_type)__lcpp_z);
           ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:533:46: note: candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY float       hypot(       float __x,       float __y,       float __z ) { return sqrt(__x*__x + __y*__y + __z*__z); }
                                             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:534:46: note: candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY double      hypot(      double __x,      double __y,      double __z ) { return sqrt(__x*__x + __y*__y + __z*__z); }
                                             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:535:46: note: candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long double hypot( long double __x, long double __y, long double __z ) { return sqrt(__x*__x + __y*__y + __z*__z); }
                                             ^
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:14:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:646:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS hash<nullptr_t>
                                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:646:34: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS hash<nullptr_t>
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:638:17: note: template parameter is declared here
template <class _Tp>
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:647:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
  : public __unary_function<nullptr_t, size_t>
                            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:647:29: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
  : public __unary_function<nullptr_t, size_t>
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/unary_function.h:41:17: note: template parameter is declared here
template <class _Arg, class _Result>
                ^
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:28:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:173:3: error: non-static data member cannot be constexpr; did you intend to make it const?
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__value_init_tag(), __value_init_tag()) {}
  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:728:31: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR'
#    define _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR constexpr
                              
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing Xcode, as well as the CommandLineTools.

I've also tried the steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250743/mac-xcode-g-cannot-compile-even-a-basic-c-program-issues-with-standard-libr)
but nothing has worked.

I have also added this to my .zshrc:

```
export CPATH=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

What should I do to make my .cpp files compile?

`ls -lh` of `\Library\Developer\CommandLineTools\SDKs` shows:

```
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B 12 Mar 12:40 MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX14.4.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel   224B 12 May  2023 MacOSX13.3.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B 12 Mar 12:39 MacOSX13.sdk -> MacOSX13.3.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel   224B 19 Feb 19:28 MacOSX14.4.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B 12 Mar 12:38 MacOSX14.sdk -> MacOSX14.4.sdk
```

Environment variables:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.xODP4nMDfe/Listeners
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.23
COLORFGBG=7;0
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
PWD=/Users/myname
SHELL=/bin/zsh
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.googlecode.iterm2
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.4.23
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
PATH=/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/myname/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
TERM=xterm-256color
HOME=/Users/myname
TMPDIR=/var/folders/bf/ynvdz9294yl3b5v2hn5kg11m0000gp/T/
USER=myname
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
LOGNAME=myname
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t1p0:6B7014C1-5EDB-4218-9A47-80371E817BDB
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:82
SHLVL=1
OLDPWD=/Users/myname
GEM_HOME=/Users/myname/.gem
RBENV_SHELL=zsh
PYENV_ROOT=/Users/myname/.pyenv
PYENV_SHELL=zsh
CPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
LIBRARY_PATH=:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: What is shown by `clang++ --version`?

Comment: I get this:

```Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin)```

Comment: Did your compile command have that colon in it? Or was the code copied and pasted?

Comment: It didn't I just added that to show the error
my command: ```clang++ -std=c++17 e.cpp -o test```

Comment: That makes no sense. And I'm suspicious of the path to a Ventura SDK. In `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/`, what does an `ls -lh` show? I have a 13.3 SDK, but the symlink `MacOSX.sdk` points to 14.4 for me. And what's the purpose of the `CPATH` export? It is not necessary.

Comment: The ```CPATH``` is  what I saw from another solution but it's not working.
```ls -lh``` shows:

```total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B 12 Mar 12:40 MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX14.4.sdk

drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel   224B 12 May  2023 MacOSX13.3.sdk

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B 12 Mar 12:39 MacOSX13.sdk -> MacOSX13.3.sdk

drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel   224B 19 Feb 19:28 MacOSX14.4.sdk

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B 12 Mar 12:38 MacOSX14.sdk -> MacOSX14.4.sdk
```

Comment: Please [edit] that last comment into your question. It's not readable as a comment.

Comment: It's sounding more and more like you threw a bunch of stuff against the wall, and now the wall is a mess and needs to be cleaned. The easiest way will be to wipe out *everything* related to a C++ environment, and then pick *one* solution. The simplest being `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Sorry, I've added it now

Comment: I have run ```xcode-select --install```

which then gives me this:

```xcode-select: note: Command line tools are already installed. Use "Software Update" in System Settings or the softwareupdate command line interface to install updates
```

Comment: That was the final step. You skipped over the "wipe out *everything* related to a C++ environment" part. Uninstall all tools and environments, clean up your environment, etc.

Comment: So would there be more to that than just uninstalling the ```CommandLineTools``` ?

Comment: Your paths are wrong? Run `xcodebuild -showsdks` to see what SDKs you have installed. Path: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include` and should be able to compile from command-line.

Comment: So in
```/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include```
I run ```xcodebuild -showsdks``` but it shows 
```xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance```

Comment: I now ran

```sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer```
in ```/Applications/Xcode.app```

I get this:
```xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer```
and when i do ```xcodebuild -showsdks``` in
```/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include ``` i get the following:

```macOS SDKs:
 macOS 14.4                     -sdk macosx14.4
 macOS 14.4                     -sdk macosx14.4```

Comment: Can you dump your environment so we can see the environment variables!

Comment: Those are exports, not your environment. You run `printenv` from the console.

Comment: Sorry I've updated it now in the post

Comment: And like I've been saying, the you need to clean house with regard to your many attempts at a C++ environment and start over from scratch. I add to my PATH multiple times under various conditions in my zshrc, but I have no repeats (like you do). At a minimum, remove any brew packages related to C++, remove CPATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH from your environment, clean up your PATH variable (by figuring out how you're repeating into it and remedying that), and at least reset the XCode Command Line Tools (`sudo xcode-select --reset`).

Comment: I would test by writing a hello world from scratch in any basic text editor, and trying to compile from the command line.

Comment: It's not that getting a C++ environment is so complicated. My guess is that the guides you were following weren't great, and you mixed and matched around until something finally broke. Most Mac users just need to either install XCode from the App Store or run `xcode-select --install`. And that's it. By the time you need something fancier, you would probably have the necessary knowledge to get it without hassle.