error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1
I have the error "error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1" when trying to install python package QuTip via Juyter notebook:

and below "error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1"

= = = =
What fixes can be tried for such error?
= = = =
EDIT: From "g++ --version" I got:
Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin24.1.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"
= = = =
EDIT 2: Error message from Terminal
qutip/core/data/matmul.cpp:806:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
806 | #include 
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for qutip
Failed to build qutip
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (qutip)
= = = =
with verbose:

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/qutip/core/data
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -I./qutip/core/data -I/private/var/folders/yx/m2j_vzc92x90rz6pvbtyr5yh0000gp/T/pip-build-env-54zb7hd_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/_core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c qutip/core/data/ptrace.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/qutip/core/data/ptrace.o -w -O3 -funroll-loops -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
qutip/core/data/ptrace.cpp:810:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
810 | #include 
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for qutip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
full command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/yx/m2j_vzc92x90rz6pvbtyr5yh0000gp/T/tmpb5xnoy6m
cwd: /private/var/folders/yx/m2j_vzc92x90rz6pvbtyr5yh0000gp/T/pip-install-nhnwe50w/qutip_eac9898a4af34fe48af890fadb95feae
Building wheel for qutip (pyproject.toml) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for qutip
Failed to build qutip
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (qutip)

= = = =

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Include them as text instead.

The core problem seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250743/mac-xcode-g-cannot-compile-even-a-basic-c-program-issues-with-standard-libr , you can try some of the suggested fixes from there.

Have you installed Xcode through the Apple store?  The problem here seems to be that you have the compiler, but it can't find the normal include files.

@Tim, thanks I have installed Xcode and from Terminal: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

and in Terminal: which xcodebuild
/usr/bin/xcodebuild

Minor comment: I don't think it is going to help impacting here in any way, however, using and sharing use of outdated approaches doesn't help you or anyone seeing this, in the long run. Please update your use to use the magic variation of the pip install command when running inside an active Jupyter Notebook session. In this case, it would be specifically, %pip install qutip. The magic pip command variation was added in 2019 to ensure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook. The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to ....

 See more about the modern %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Related tip: pip is limited in abilities in regards to what it can do on your machine compared to Anaconda/conda. Seeing qutip here, I cannot help but think it may be that you are looking to do complex things and would be better off moving on to something more capable. Just a suggestion to consider, I may be totally wrong and it will be fine for you uses. You can see that conda-forge has that to install here. If you do chose Anaconda/conda, make sure to go over the getting started material as it is particular about environment/project management.

Jupyter itself doesn't install anything, it comes bundled with Python/Pip which can be used to install dependencies.
Right now your issue is with compiling C code as evident by G++ erroring out. You need to make sure you have all the required dependencies. QuTip requires C++11 or higher. You can check your version with:
g++ --version
If you need to update, it'll depend on what system you have:
brew install gcc or sudo apt-get install g++-11
You should also ensure the correct C compilers and standards are being used:
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
pip install qutip --no-cache-dir

Finally you can try installing with verbose mode for more details:
pip install --verbose qutip
I was able to install this package without issue.

Thanks, from "g++ --version" I got:
Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin24.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"

I then copy pasted your 4 lines of code and ran but got the same error "1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1
error: subprocess-exited-with-error" Sorry, I am not good with these things - what else can I try please?

To be clear, those are bash commands. They can't be run in Jupyter (at least I don't think so). Are you running those in terminal or Jupter?

Sorry, I ran these 4 lines in Terminal and got the same error message

You can try running pip with verbose enabled for more details. Is it still failing at #include <algorithm>?

Yes this is still the fail point :-(

qutip/core/data/dia.cpp:810:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
810 | #include 
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1
